# Hired an electrician to replace a buzzing electrical socket switch - it's still buzzing

Tags: switch

I have a switch that controls power to the top socket of a standard two socket wall power outlet. The bottom socket is always active, but the top socket is controlled by the switch.

A few weeks ago I heard that switch buzzing, so I hired an electrician that same day to check it out. They replaced the switch and I didn't hear anything after so I thought the issue was resolved.

However a couple of days ago I heard the buzzing again coming directly from that switch.

I installed an aquarium a month ago - so there are two electrical devices very recently plugged into that outlet. I plugged the aquarium filter in the bottom socket which is always on, and I plugged the aquarium lights into the top socket so I would have the option of conveniently turning off the lights.

I already paid an electrician $200 and the issue is still there so I want to get advice on what the issue might be before hiring an electrician again.

Comment: Usually work done is guaranteed for more than a few weeks.   Switches and/or sockets/receptacles should not buzz.  I imagine you checked for bees in the wall and the buzz was coming from that switch.  I would get that electrician back and check for what is causing that buzz.

Comment: Do you mean that the electrician might come back and solve the problem without an additional fee? I'm in Canada, I don't know what the standard practice is, but I thought that you always pay for an electrician's time regardless of whether or not they fix the issue.

Comment: All professionals stand behind their work.  It is possible the switch is not the problem and if you only ask them to replace the switch and not tell them what the problem was/is, that is on you.  If you told them about the buzzing and it comes back, that is on them.

Comment: Are you sure you're not picking up a vibration or buzz from the pump and it's traveling up the hollow wall?

Comment: I have a crappy dimmer switch in a room and it buzzes whenever the switch is not physically placed quite right. If I adjust it a little bit it stops buzzing. I think some switches are just garbage

Comment: @crip659 is right. In any case, when this or another electrician is in the house, confirm that they hear the noise you are hearing and that their job is to stop the buzzing. In the old days of CRT monitors, those often contained a "flyback transformer" which could make a high-pitched whine.  While most younger people could hear it, middle-aged repair persons often could no longer hear those higher frequencies and so didn't hear any problem.